# Converting Powershell script to LogicApps

Tags: rest, azure-logic-apps

I need to populate a Logic App based on a Powershell script.  Any clues?
I need an http request as a trigger.

I have filled in the URI with what's in the $baseuri variable.  I've also put this in headers.
    {
    "Accept": "text/json",
    "Content-Type: "
    text / json "
    }
How do populate the body?

```
<pre>
#Core Parameters
$baseuri = "https://test"
$header = @{
    "Accept" = "text/json"
    "Content-Type" = "text/json"
}
$G_header = @{"Accept" = "text/json"}
#Login
Write-Output "Login ..."
$uri_login = $baseuri + "SPDEDJSONSERVICE.LOGIN"
$body_login = @{"method"="login";"username"="qqq";"password"="qqq"} | ConvertTo-Json
$Conn = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post $uri_login -Headers $header -Body $body_login
$SessionID = $conn.sessionID

#This is where we would code the data extraction
Write-Output "Gathering Data ..."
$uri_DefGrid = $baseuri + "SPDEDMHAPI.GRIDGET"
$body_DefGrid = @{"sessionID"=$SessionID;"FORMAT"="payload";"GRIDID"="PROP";"GRIDVIEW"="1";"FROM"=0;"HITS"=100;"PROFILE"=@(@{"PR_USER1"="GENERATED";"PR_NAME"="G*"});"ORDERBY"="PR_DATESOLD"} | ConvertTo-Json
$Grid = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post $uri_DefGrid -Headers $header -Body $body_DefGrid
$Grid.Payload | where {$_.PR_OWN -eq "SC-CO-001"} | Select-Object -Property PR_SNAM, PR_OWN, PR_NAME, PR_ADD4, PR_TENR, PR_USER1 | Export-Clixml -Path "C:\Test\API\XML_Sample.xml"
$Grid.Payload | Select-Object -Property PR_SNAM, PR_OWN, PR_NAME, PR_ADD4, PR_TENR, PR_USER1 | Format-Table -AutoSize

#Logout
Write-Output "Logging Out ..."
$uri_logout = $baseuri + "SPDEDJSONSERVICE.LOGOUT"
$body_logout = @{"method"="logout";"sessionID"=$SessionID} | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post $uri_logout -Headers $header -Body $body_logout
<code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, azure logic seems not support to run powershell and cli script, here is a [voice in azure feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/33913552-run-a-powershell-code-within-a-logic-app-action), you could vote it.

**Workaround**:

You could set Http Header as `"Content_Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

For `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the body of the HTTP message sent to the server is essentially one giant query string -- name/value pairs are separated by the ampersand (`&`), and names are separated from values by the equals symbol (`=`). So the request body should be:

```
method=login&username=qqq&password=qqq
```

The designer snap is as below:

[image]

Comment: This is great.  Thank you.  Assuming the above is an http request, what should I do to trap the response?

Comment: If you want to get response body, you could use Initialize variable to get your Body. Like this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuSCm.png).

Comment: It's saying Bad request.  Here are the raw inputs.  {
    "uri": "https://test",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "text/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "body": "method=login&username=qqq&password=qqq"
}

Comment: What the error message? Do you sure your request can be visit in postman?

Comment: I had put test instead of testSPDEDJSONSERVICE.LOGIN.  Now it's giving error code 302.  Redirect.  I will try Postman.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202321/discussion-between-joey-cai-and-alhal).

Comment: In Postman I have the headers as you say.  For the body what goes in key and what goes in value?

Comment: I got it working in Postman by switching off SSL certificate verification.  I need to do this in logic apps.   But your answer has worked.